# Gif size impact on mail size when received in inbox

Tags: html, email, html-email, gif, email-client

I have made a html email with a 10 mb gif in, the mail itself, when received is only 84kb. I'm trying to figure out if the 10mb is just downloaded when the mail is opened as any other image, or if it more like streaming a video, so it's downloaded while you watching it.
I can't find any information online on how .gifs are treated by mail clients.

Comment: is it embedded or a link to an image? if its only a link then the email should not be large. If its embedded, then it would be larger. im guessing the email client has a form of html reader that downloads the images if they are urls. Similar to older browsers.

Comment: its just a normal href="www." to the file

Comment: So if its only href, then the image is not present in the e-mail, but only url link to itself. So it will not contains 10MB of image content.

Comment: Its first when the user views the .gif it will download the 10mb from the server then?

Comment: No, it will download nothing, because .gif is not embed to the e-mail; e-mail contains only url to the image. So receiver of the e-mail can click on that url and it will open the image in his browser (and the browser will download that image).

Answer (score 1):

If the image is embedded then the email should be larger.
If it's an img tag with url then it shouldn't be larger.

[This](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) blog post discusses the pros and cons of embedding images vs not embedding.

Answer (score 0):

So if its only href, then the image is not present in the e-mail, but only url link to itself. So it will not contains 10MB of image content.

It will download no image, because .gif is not embed to the e-mail; e-mail contains only url to the image. So receiver of the e-mail can click on that url and it will open the image in his browser (and the browser will download that image).

Comment: But when the .gif is within the mail <td><img href="hello.gif" /></td>, it is shown when they "view images" or just opens the mail. And if that gif is 10mb, it will start to download it on the phone.